# Picard group of a Affine scheme

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How do we define a Picard group of an Affine scheme? Is there way to define as for commutative ring? Thanks

Comment: You can define it for any scheme. Check Mumford, Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Picard group can be defined for any scheme $X$ as the group of isomorphism classes of invertible sheaves ( $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules that are locally free of rank $1$). Given such an $\mathcal{L}$, its inverse is given by $\mathcal{L}^{\vee} = \mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{O}_X)$ where Hom there is not global Hom but rather *sheaf Hom* (which is a sheaf). The multiplication in the group is given by the tensor product, and to check $\text{Pic} (X)$ is a  group the only non-trivial calculation is to see that
$$\mathcal{L} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{L}^\vee = \mathcal{O}_X.$$

If you want to check this isomorphism, I suggest you consider the tensor-hom adjunction.

Comment: Actually the Picard group can be defined for any ringed space (or even ringed site).

Comment: Thank you all. I was wandering is there some characterization of scheme by Picard group

Answer (score 14):

Addition to the other answer: If $X = \mathrm{Spec}(A)$, then $\mathrm{Pic}(X)=\mathrm{Pic}(A)$ is simply the group of isomorphism classes of finitely generated projective $A$-modules of rank $1$. It is known that the following are equivalent for some $A$-module $M$:

1. $M$ is finitely generated projective of rank $1$.
2. There are elements $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$ of $A$ which generate the unit ideal such that, for every $i$, $M_{f_i}$ is free of rank $1$ over $A_{f_i}$.
3. There is some $A$-module $N$ such that $M \otimes_A N \cong A$.

The group multiplication is given by $[M] \otimes [M'] := [M \otimes_A M']$, the inversion is given by $[M]^{-1} := [M^*]$, where $M^* := \hom_A(M,A)$ is the dual. As a simple example, you can show for a field $k$ that $\mathrm{Pic}(k)$ is trivial. For a nontrivial example, see below.

If $A$ is an integral domain, the Picard group is known as the class group, and we can add

$~~~   4.$ $M$ is isomorphic to an invertible fractional ideal of $A$, i.e. a finitely generated $A$-submodule $I$ of $\mathrm{Q}(A)$ which has an inverse $J$ in the sense that $I \cdot J = A$.

The class group is the quotient group $\{$invertible fractional ideals$\}$ / $\{$principal ideals$\}$, with the simple multiplication $I \cdot I' := \langle a \cdot b : a \in I , b \in I' \rangle$. For example, take $A=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $J = (2,1-\sqrt{-5})$. Then one calculates $I \cdot J = (2)$. Hence, $\frac{1}{2} J$ is inverse to $I$, and $I$ is invertible. But since $I$ not principal, it represents a nontrivial element in $\mathrm{Pic}(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}])$ (which turns out to be cyclic of order $2$).

Comment: I think I can find all of this in some chapter in Eisenbud no (The viewpoint of divisors from algebraic geometry)?

Comment: Of course, it's nice to note that in the case of Dedekind domains, your definition of class group coincides with the normal once since, there, all fractional ideals are invertible (this is an equivalent characterization of DDs). So, you can apply methods such as Minkowski theory to (somewhat easily) show your somewhat mysterious claim that, in fact, $\text{Pic}(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}])=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. (+1) by the way :)