# Line bundles on affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $A$ is a UFD, all the line bundles on $\text{Spec}~A$ is trivial. Is there any generalizations of this about when the Picard group of an affine scheme is trivial? Or are there any theorems about the structures of the Picard groups of affine schemes on some classes of nice rings, say Noetherian integral domains? This seems to be a very general (and vague) question, which I apologize first.

Comment: Here is a nice answer to your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/527474/317129